# How to set a specific text to every TEdit?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am super newbie and tried to write following code which sets every `TEdit.Text` to one mentioned in code

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  Edit : TEdit;
begin
  for i := 0 to Edit.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    with Edit.Components[i] do
    begin
      Text := 'Done';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the mistakes that I can see:

1. You never assign a value to `Edit`.
2. Typically the form owns all the components, and so a `TEdit` will have zero owned components.
3. `Edit.Components[i]` is of type `TComponent` which does not have a `Text` property. If your code compiles, then `Text` is actually that of the form. The lesson you should learn from this point is never to use `with` ever again.

You should solve this using code like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Edit: TEdit;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount-1 do begin
    if Components[i] is TEdit then begin
      Edit := TEdit(Components[i]);
      Edit.Text := 'Done';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note that here we are using `ComponentCount` and `Components[]` from the form itself. We have removed the evil `with` statement. And we have had to cast the component to a reference of type `TEdit`, after first using the `is` operator to check the type of the component.

This approach will work so long as the form owns all the edits found within it. However, if you create controls dynamically, or if you use frames or parented forms, then this approach, based on ownership via `Components[]` will not yield all the controls. In such more complex cases you would need to iterate using the parent/child relationship using `ControlCount` and `Controls[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @David Herrernan

Answer (score 3):

*What am I doing wrong?* Just about everything. What I think you are trying to achieve is to put the same text in all TEdits on the form. So you need to go through all the components in TForm (not Edit!) and and check that each is really a Tedit, and if so assign the text. Like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer; 
begin
   for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
   begin
     if Components[ I ] is TEdit then
     begin   
        (Components[ I ] as TEdit).Text := 'Done';
     end;
   end;
end;
```

As an aside - avoid using 'with'. It just cases ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: Thank you So Much

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over all child controls of the form, and if the current control is a `TEdit`, then you set its text. If the current control is a windowed control, it might have child controls of its own, and you need to redo  same thing for this control. Hence, let's use recursion:

```
procedure SetAllEdits(AParent: TWinControl; const AText: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AParent.ControlCount - 1 do
    if AParent.Controls[i] is TCustomEdit then
      TCustomEdit(AParent.Controls[i]).Text := AText
    else if AParent.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
      SetAllEdits(TWinControl(AParent.Controls[i]), AText);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetAllEdits(Self, 'test');
end;
```

There are other ways, like subclassing the edit control and having the new class respond to broadcasted messages.

Comment: Thank you So much

Answer (score 1):

Answer from D. Heffernan is already good, I'm trying to make it easier to understand for beginner.
In this code, we do "typecast" TEdit to TComponent by command: aEdit := TEdit(aComponent), because TEdit is inherited from TComponent.

What you get from iteration (for ...) is TComponent, not TEdit. You get TEdit by "typecast" it.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  aComponent : TComponent;
  aEdit : TEdit;

begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount-1 do 
  begin
    aComponent := Components[i];
    if aComponent is TEdit then 
    begin
      aEdit := TEdit(aComponent);
      aEdit.Text := 'Done';
    end;
  end;
end;
```